# помогите правильно вывести данные из json в html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

validate__reg.php

```
$error_fields = [];

$error_length = [];

if(strlen($login) < 6){  
    $error_fields[] = 'login';
    $error_length[] = 'Логин не может быть меньше 6 символов';
}

if(strlen($email) < 6){
    $error_fields[] = 'email';
    $error_length[] = 'Email не может быть меньше 6 символов';
}

$dog = "@";

if(strpos($email, $dog) === false){
    $error_fields[] = 'email';
}

if(strlen($password) < 6){
    $error_fields[] = 'password';
    $error_length[] = 'Пароль не может быть меньше 6 символов';
}

if(strlen($passwordConfirm) < 6){
    $error_fields[] = 'passwordConfirm';
}


if(!empty($error_fields)){
    $response = [
        "status" => false,
        "type" => 1,
        "fields" => $error_fields,
        "length" => $error_length
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

reg.js

```
 data.length.forEach(function(leng) {
    $('.form-text').html(leng);
 });
```

html

```
<div class="form-text"></div>
```

нужно чтобы под каждым inputом выводилось сообщение которое присвоено $error_length[], а выводится одинаковое у всех, которое записано в массив самым последним.
как сейчас выводится - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHulu.png

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 data.length.forEach(function(leng, index) {
    $(`.form-text:eq(index)`).html(leng);
 });
```

Но подход не совсем корректный, потому что где-то поля могут быть заполнены корректно, а вы пытаетесь по всем пробегаться. Нужно как минимум знать какому полю какие ошибки показывать, например в массив с errors держать ключи для полей и уже к каждому ключю вести в соответствие свои ошибки